# Java Regex to replace Substring

Tags: java, regex

```
String expression = "${abcd?string(datePattern)}\" href=\"\">From Date</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;${dasfsaf?string(datePattern)}\" href=\"\">To Date</a>";
expression=expression.replaceAll("(})(\".+</a>)(.+?)", "$1$3");
System.out.println(expression);
```

The output that is coming is :

```
${abcd?string(datePattern)}&nbsp;-&nbsp;${dasfsaf?string(datePattern)}" href="">To Date</a>
```

The expected Output is :

```
${abcd?string(datePattern)}&nbsp;-&nbsp;${dasfsafT?string(datePattern)}
```

The problem is it is only replacing the content between the first `{` and `</a>` and not the ones after that. I want all content to be replaced between these two..

Answer (score 1):

in your regex you require there to be something after the `</a>` as you have `(.+?)` you can change that to `(.*?)` and it should work as you are no longer requiring there to be anything afterwards and your second part can match (alternatively, it doesn't appear to have any role so I would just delete it). In addition you probably don't want the greedy quantifier in the middle `.+` so change that to lazy `.+?`

```
expression=expression.replaceAll("(})(\".+?</a>)", "$1");
```

Answer (score -1):

Not the exact regex answer but you can simply repeat the replaceAll call. That's what i do when i don't have time and if it won't be costly.

Comment: the regex will not match a second time, it requires there to be something present after the final `</a>` or it won't match.

Comment: The output was one repeat more than what expected at the end. So @user3678399 managed to replace one in the middle but not the one at the end. I've already told it was not the exact answer. Sometimes i need an urgent answer and when it comes to such complex regex phrases you may need to see opinions. Thats why there are so much questions on different regexes. And i wanted to suggest that idea.